# how can I pass a typescript expression into an angular 2 component

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to pass a simple expression into my Angular component.

This is how I want to use it:

*in parent html:*

```
<my-component [expression]="$context.foo.bar" [items]="Items"></my-component>
```

*in my-component code:*

```
@Input() expression: Function;
@Input() items: any[];
...
const results = this.items.map(item => this.expression(item)); // $context = item
```

I can pass a reference to a method, but it takes a lot of time and effort to pass such a simple expression.

Can I implement as I mentioned above?

Arrow functions are not allowed in angular template syntax.

Comment: do you want your child component to access a method from your parent component?

Comment: why you want to pass a method reference component ??

Comment: @chiril.sarajiu no, i want passing expression like arrow function to use it in the child component. To pass a reference to the method of the parent component is a simple method, but requires the declaration of a separate method. I want to use an anonymous function for use in child component

Comment: @UnluckyAj I want to make the sorting mechanism in my component by the property of an element independent of the structure of the element. Like sort() function with function that serves as a key for the sort comparison in python

Comment: What do u mean about eval functions in code? If string creating in code, not user?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible. What I would suggest you to do is to use a public method. So in the parent component you can define your public method and then you can use it on the child component

Answer (score 0):

```
<componentB #cmpB>
</componentB>
<div (click)="cmpB.editFunction()">
    This is where i want the function to be called
</div>
```

you could do something like above if its just another component whose function you want to access

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a bad thing that will probably break change detection mechanism. Instead in the parent component you should execute `expression` on the array items and pass result to a child component. If you really want the child component to have access to external expression then it should be moved to a service that is provided by your parent component. Check for `forwardRef` that will allow to use the instance of the component as provider for some injection token.

Comment: Why does this break the changes detection? I can pass the reference to the parent method to the child component, and this will be correct. But I want to do this without declaring this method in the typescript code of the parent component. Just a small expression, similar to the arrow function in the template

Comment: Because the parent component may need to be updated when you call it's method. But the changes in the child component that may trigger the parent's method will not check the parent component. Well, technically it's possible to pass parent's method to child and execute it from a child. This just what framework is designed NOT TO DO, because it's a silly thing that makes everything too much complicated.